# Issue inserting XML element with ElementTree when characters are too long

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I'm having an issue with inserting text into a specific element in an XML tree.

My goal is to take an image, convert it to base64, then insert the base64 string into an element.
Below is my current code:

```
with open("t.png", "rb") as imageFile:
    str = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())


tree=ElementTree()
tree = ET.parse('image-template.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for z in root.iter('body'):
    z.text=(str)
tree.write('new_branding.xml')
```

If I insert a variable with a shorter character length the code seems to work properly.  When I try inserting the long character length of a base64 string I get the following error:

```
" "cannot serialize %r (type %s)" % (text, type(text).__name__)"
```

Is there something I need to add to my for loop to insert longer strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands, your `str` variable is actually of type `bytes`. You can test this by putting a `print(type(str))` statement after you declare `str`. It will print `<class 'bytes'>`.

To get it working, you first of all should change the name of your `str` variable so that you aren't overwriting the built-in `str()` function.

If you change it to, say, `imageString`, you can then change the line where you declare it to something like `imageString = str(base64.b64encode(imageFile.read()))`. Note that we're using `str()` to convert your variable from bytes to a string: that's why you need to change the name.

Anyway, that should work, or at least it does on my end.

Comment: That did it.  Thank you!